# Why would three out of four very similar ajax calls work as posts and the fourth one only works as a get?

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-4

I have a MVC View with four sections in it ( Not Partial Views ) that each have its own save button. These save buttons at not to save the entire form just a field or two of data into parts of the view model. They are Alias, Default, Format and Specials. In the view there is a javascript/jQuery function to call the controller for each save button. The ajax code for Alias only works when it and its associated controller method are defined as GET's. The other three work perfectly fine as POST's.

I have tried the SaveAlias code configured as both a POST and a Get. With a breakpoint set in the controller method, it is never reached when setup as a POST. If I try the same setup with the other three as POST's the breakpoint is reached properly.

// javascript in View OnSaveAlias() Works as GET
// Does not work if configured as a POST.

```
function OnSaveAlias() {
    $('#AliasClearButton').removeClass("d-none");
    $('#AliasClearButton').addClass("d-block");
    var name = $('#ActiveEntity_Alias_Alias').val();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        datatype: "json",
        url: '@Url.Action("SaveAliasG", "Entities")',
        data: { Name: name },
        contentType: 'application/json',
        success: function (message) {
            if (message) {
                $alert('Error');
            } else {
                window.location.href = "Create";
            }
        }
    });
};
```

// Corresponding Controller Code For GET

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult SaveAliasG(String Name)
{
    WFViewModel = (WorkflowVM)TempData.Peek("WFViewModel");
    WFViewModel.ActiveEntity.Alias.Alias = Name;
    WFViewModel.ActiveEntity.AliasesSaved = true;
    SelectListItem newItem = new SelectListItem()
    {
        Text = Name,
        Value = "0"
    };
    WFViewModel.ActiveEntity.EntityAliasList.Add(newItem);
    TempData["WFViewModel"] = WFViewModel;
    return null;
}
```

// JavaScript and controller code for Default which works as a POST

```
function OnSaveDefault() {
    $('#DefaultsClearButton').removeClass("d-none");
    $('#DefaultsClearButton').addClass("d-block");
    var name = $('#ActiveEntity_DefVals_DefaultValue').val();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        datatype: "json",
        url: '@Url.Action("SaveDefaultP", "Entities")',
        data: { Name: name },
        contentType: 'application/json',
        success: function (message) {
            if (message) {
               $alert('Error');
            } else {
               window.location.href = "Create";
            }
        }
    });
};
```

// Corresponding Controller Code For POST

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult SaveDefaultP(String Name)
{
    WFViewModel = (WorkflowVM)TempData.Peek("WFViewModel");
    WFViewModel.ActiveEntity.DefVals.DefaultValue = Name;
    WFViewModel.ActiveEntity.DefaultsSaved = true;
    TempData["WFViewModel"] = WFViewModel;
    return null;
}
```

NO visible error messages and none seen when having breakpoints set in javascript code through F12 debugger.

Comment: You post an object with a `Name` property, but your method does not accept such an object, just a simple parameter. Create a class with a `public string Name { get; set; }` and I suspect it would work. Maybe the `GET` receives special threatment from jQuery or Mvc.

Comment: Thanks @Silvermind, The parameter configs for both the POST's and the GET's are the same. Both methods are expecting a String Variable.

Comment: Yes, That's what I said :). Now change it into a class object with a `Name` property.

Comment: Thanks @mjwills. What exactly do you mean by payloads for both the URL and the body? I do not use Chrome Developer tools and would prefer not to install it on my system unless absolutely necessary. Also what is your definition of Server Side Action? In my world it is the methods in the controller.

Comment: Hello @mjwills. No that is not correct. What I have included in the question are two out of the four sets of javascript and Action methods of the four mentioned in the statement of issue. Three of them are setup and work fine as POST's just like SaveDefaultP.  The question is why when I have SaveAliasG set up both in the javascript and controller as POST won't it work like the other three. It only works like the other three if it is configured as a GET.

Comment: Hello @mjwills. The SaveAliasG Action Method is in the code snippets above as well as the OnSaveAlias javascript snippet that calls SaveAliasG.

Comment: Hello @mjwills. I currently have the [HttpPost]SaveAliasP code commented out. It is identical to the SaveAliasG code you can see except [HttpGet] is replaced with [HttpPost] The G in the name is changed to a P. Additionally, the javascript is the same for OnSaveAlias except type: is set to POST instead of GET and the url is url: '@Url.Action("SaveAliasP", "Entities")', instead of url: '@Url.Action("SaveAliasG", "Entities")',

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the POST that is working and the POST that isn't working in the same controller?

`@Url.Action("SaveDefaultP", "Entities")'` results in `/Entities/SaveDefaultP` but it's not the method name that it's trying to match with. It's the Route. If your controller only has one `[HttpPost]` it will automatically route to that method. If you have two `[HttpPost]` methods then I think it just finds the first one.

Try switching the GET back to a POST but add an attribute to each method for `Route`.

Comment: Hello@James. Thanks for the thoughts. As the code sits there are at least three Posts that all work properly in addition to the one that does not work as a post. And all four are in the same controller.

Comment: @R.Ruggles did you maybe map the routes for the other ones and maybe forgot this one?

Comment: I have not explicitly mapped any routes.